# Make all net clients of a wifi router on a subnet have IP addresses in the form of clients of the parent router

Tags: routing, dhcp, router

i have an ADSL wifi Zyxel router connecter to outer internet and it serves IP addresses in the form of 10.0.0.x by DHCP - which is correct. Then i have a TP-Link wif router connected to Zyxel as a client, which serves DHCP addresses 192.168.1.x. Can I configure TP-Link'c network clients (TV, Nintendo, Satellite) to obtain IP addresses in the form that the parent router serves? which is 10.0.0.x? Then all devices on the network can for exeample print on a printer 10.0.0.4?

BTW you see, i'm a total newbie in networking :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Can I configure TP-Link'c network clients (TV, Nintendo, Satellite) to
> obtain IP addresses in the form that the parent router serves? which
> is 10.0.0.x?

Yes.

In summary, do the following 3 steps.

1. Hook up a LAN port of the TP-Link to a LAN port on the ADSL box.
2. Give the TP-Link router a Static IP address on the ADSL box.
3. Turn DHCP OFF on the TP-Link router.

Now you should restart the TP-Link and make sure it connects. It should I do this very frequently.

All devices will now be on the same subnet.

You should be prepared to do a factory reset on the TP-Link if necessary (an error was made).